# ZLIB Decompression - Client Side

Tags: javascript, zlib, compression

I am receiving data as an "**ZLIB**" compressed inputstream.

Using Javascript/Ajax/JQuery, I need to uncompress it on the client side.

Is there a way to do so?

I already have this working in JAVA as below, but need to do this on Client Side.

```
url = new URL(getCodeBase(), dataSrcfile); 
URLConnection urlConn = url.openConnection();
urlConn.setUseCaches(false); 
InputStream in = urlConn.getInputStream();
InflaterInputStream inflate = new InflaterInputStream(in);
InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inflate);
InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(in);
BufferedReader bufReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
// Read until no more '#'
int i = 0;
int nHidden = 0;
String line1;
do //------------------------Parsing Starts Here
{
    line1 = bufReader.readLine();
.............
...... so on
```

Comment: Why? Just use HTTP compression, the browser will handle that transparently.

Comment: What if the server side already exists and cannot be changed? I agree that it would be better to do the compression at the HTTP level. But you're not always given a choice.

Comment: Did you try compiling the zlib C code to javascript? It seems like Emscripten could do this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Decompress gzip and zlib string in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14620769/decompress-gzip-and-zlib-string-in-javascript)

Answer (score 29):

[Pako](https://github.com/nodeca/pako) is a full and modern `Zlib` port.

Here is a very simple example and you can work from there.

Get [pako.js](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nodeca/pako/master/dist/pako.js) and you can decompress byteArray like so:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Gunzipping binary gzipped string</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="pako.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">

    // Get datastream as Array, for example:
    var charData    = [31,139,8,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,5,193,219,13,0,16,16,4,192,86,214,151,102,52,33,110,35,66,108,226,60,218,55,147,164,238,24,173,19,143,241,18,85,27,58,203,57,46,29,25,198,34,163,193,247,106,179,134,15,50,167,173,148,48,0,0,0];

    // Turn number array into byte-array
    var binData     = new Uint8Array(charData);

    // Pako magic
    var data        = pako.inflate(binData);

    // Convert gunzipped byteArray back to ascii string:
    var strData     = String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint16Array(data));

    // Output to console
    console.log(strData);

  </script>
</head>
<body>
    Open up the developer console.
</body>
</html>
```

Running example: http://jsfiddle.net/9yH7M/

Alternatively you can base64 encode the array before you send it over as the Array takes up a lot of overhead when sending as JSON or XML. Decode likewise:

```
// Get some base64 encoded binary data from the server. Imagine we got this:
var b64Data     = 'H4sIAAAAAAAAAwXB2w0AEBAEwFbWl2Y0IW4jQmziPNo3k6TuGK0Tj/ESVRs6yzkuHRnGIqPB92qzhg8yp62UMAAAAA==';

// Decode base64 (convert ascii to binary)
var strData     = atob(b64Data);

// Convert binary string to character-number array
var charData    = strData.split('').map(function(x){return x.charCodeAt(0);});

// Turn number array into byte-array
var binData     = new Uint8Array(charData);

// Pako magic
var data        = pako.inflate(binData);

// Convert gunzipped byteArray back to ascii string:
var strData     = String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint16Array(data));

// Output to console
console.log(strData);
```

Running example: http://jsfiddle.net/9yH7M/1/

To go more advanced, here is the [`pako` API documentation](http://nodeca.github.io/pako/).

Comment: Thanks for the constructive comment about why my working example is being downvoted.

Comment: To get a string from the uncompressed data, you can also just do as follow: `var strData = pako.inflate(binData, { to: 'string' });`. See options here: http://nodeca.github.io/pako/#inflate

Answer (score 13):

A more recent offering is https://github.com/imaya/zlib.js

I think it's much better than the alternatives.

Comment: I'd rather use library with english documentation, this one has readme in some asian language, looks japanese or chinese to me.

Comment: I fail to see how that matters. The API is clear if you're familiar with zlib. This library is very well-designed, fast, and easy to use.

Comment: The English documentation is available by clicking the link marked [English Documentation](https://github.com/imaya/zlib.js/blob/master/README.en.md).

Comment: I had a better experience with Pako.js than imaya/zlib.js

Answer (score 3):

Our library JSXGraph contains the deflate, unzip and gunzip algorithm. Please, have a look at jsxcompressor (a spin-off from JSXGraph, see http://jsxgraph.uni-bayreuth.de/wp/download/) or at Utils.js in the source code.

Answer (score 3):

Try pako https://github.com/nodeca/pako , it's not just inflate/deflate, but exact zlib port to javascript, with almost all features and options supported. Also, it's the fastest implementation in modern browsers.

Comment: Upvoted. Could you provide a client-side example (including which files are required)? All documentation is about using (server side) `node.js`.

Comment: There's a browser example here: https://github.com/nodeca/pako/blob/master/examples/browser.html

Answer (score 2):

Just as the first comments to your question suggest, I would suspect that you actually want the browser to handle the decompression. If I am mistaken, you might want to check out the [JSXGraph](http://jsxgraph.uni-bayreuth.de/wp/) library, it is supposed to contain pure [JS implementations for deflate and unzip](http://jsxgraph.uni-bayreuth.de/wp/2009/09/29/jsxcompressor-zlib-compressed-javascript-code/).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I am bit confused. I checked the JSXGraph, but it looks like a library to draw shapes like Arc, Circle etc. Do you please have a pure HTML and JavaScript (no PHP) example where a file (input sream)  compressed with Zlib can be un-compressed. Please help

Answer (score 1):

The [js-deflate](https://github.com/dankogai/js-deflate) project by dankogai may be what you are looking for. I haven't actually tried it, but the rawinflate.js code seems fairly minimal, and should be able to decompress DEFLATE/zlib:ed data.

Answer (score 1):

Using Pako you can decode the compressed(gzib) response, short code for above [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22675078/5782437)

```
JSON.parse(Pako.inflate(Buffer.from(data, 'base64'), { to: 'string' }))
```

[Buffer.from](https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/met_buffer_from.asp), [Pako](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pako)

Answer (score 0):

you should see [zlib rfc](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1950.txt).

the javascript inflate code I tested: [inflate in Javascript](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/scripting/Javascript_binaryenc.aspx)

the java code I wrote:

```
    static public byte[] compress(byte[] input) {
    Deflater deflater = new Deflater();
    deflater.setInput(input, 0, input.length);
    deflater.finish();
    byte[] buff = new byte[input.length + 50];
    deflater.deflate(buff);

    int compressedSize = deflater.getTotalOut();

    if (deflater.getTotalIn() != input.length)
        return null;

    byte[] output = new byte[compressedSize - 6];

    System.arraycopy(buff, 2, output, 0, compressedSize - 6);// del head and
                                                                // foot byte
    return output;
}
```

The very Important thing is in deflate in Java you must cut the head 2 byte,foot 4 byte,to get the raw deflate.

Answer (score 0):

[Browserify-zlib](https://www.npmjs.com/package/browserify-zlib) works perfectly for me, it uses pako and has the exact same api as zlib. After I struggled for days with compressing/decompressing zlib encoded payloads in client side with pako, I can say that browserify-zlib is really convenient.