# Un-archiving a file in Amazon Web Service S3

Tags: python, json, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services, zip

Currently working on a project I'm uploading a series of JSON files to Amazon S3  to be received by mobile clients.

In order to reduce costs of individual file transfers, I'm wondering if it's possible to unzip a file once it's on the S3 server as opposed to unzip a file once it's on the EC2 server than transfer it across.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

S3 doesn't directly support functionality you ask for. However, there are two things you should consider to reduce your costs and transfers:

2. Compress your JSON files before uploading, store and serve them compressed and let the browser decompress them transparently (some info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8350749/gzipped-json-file-not-decompressing))
3. Additionally you can use the Reduced Redundancy Option for storing your files (you save 50% here, but just on storage, not on transfers)