# Decompress in browser a JSON datafile served as static file from Node.js

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, gzip, http-compression

Similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8350749/gzipped-json-file-not-decompressing) need to send a large 30MB JSON file to the browser, which compresses to 3MB.  (yes, yes, it's big and intensive to decompress, but better to serve it once as a static file than as, say, 150 separate AJAX calls to a REST API, and a bit of upfront load time is okay here).

Also like the original post, it's a static file, so can compress it ahead of time (so the server doesn't need to compress it on each request).  Further, can serve it from the public directory on the server, which in  Node.js / Express.js I have marked as static:

`app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));`

One commenter replied:

*"It is also possible to precompress your JSON and then just tell Apache to serve the files with the appropriate headers to avoid having to recompress all the time."*

**Question 1:**  How might I do that in Node/Express, i.e. tell Node to tell the browser the file is in gzip format, so that the browser automatically uncompresses it?

Another answer remarks *"...but do check that the browser supports compression "*, which raises another question?

**Question 2:** Do ~most~ modern browsers have the ability to decompress content?  Or am I better off just including a javascript library for decompression, get the data via Ajax as a binary text, and always decompress it in my own code rather than browser's native utility?

(For my purpose, it's okay to exclude some old browsers, e.g. dropping IE6 would be okay, dropping support for IE9 would not)

Comment: Question 1: Look into the HTTP Content-Encoding header. Question 2: You could have two versions of the file, one compressed with gzip and one not. Then depending on the Accept-Encoding of the request, send the gzip or uncompressed one.

Comment: Serving static files from node.js is a very bad solution. Use nginx or similar. If you serve a static file from node you'll filling the event loop with callbacks that will slow your web. node.js means speed and scalability, ideal for high concurrent webs, use it the right way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The browser should automatically decompress the server response, if there is a `Content-Encoding` header.

With node.js, you would serve the already compressed file with the header:

```
Content-Encoding: gzip
```

I.E:

```
res.setHeader( "Content-Encoding", "gzip" );
```

Modern browsers support gzip, for older browsers, check http://www.schroepl.net/projekte/mod_gzip/browser.htm

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. I know how to do that if I explicitly serve the file from within a defined server route, e.g. `app.get('/api/data/:datafile', function(req,res) { ... read and return file ...}`  and that certainly is better than having node.js read *and compress* the file on each run, and avoids need for extra library.   Newbie question: is it better to avoid serving even a 1MB file via a route and serve it from a static directory if I can?   If so, can I set the headers for those?  Right now I don't have `function (req,res) {}` for those, so no `res` obj on which to set those headers.

Comment: @user645715 I doubt it matters, in your case both routes and static files are processed by node.js anyway, are they not?. Contrary to php/apache setup where you avoid a lot of overhead with static directories because a new php process does not need to be started to serve them.

Comment: @Cameron;@Esailija; Thank you so much.  I like the routes as can incorporate both ideas -- send gzip if acceptable, send raw if not. Testing, I find if I send the raw file, the server gzips and sets header fine, and the browser uncompresses it.  But if I send an already gzipped file, the server gzips *that* and the server uncompresses it to get a gzip format file, not JSON.  Arg.  I wonder if there's a way to tell the server the file was *already* zipped, and just set the header.  But practically, this is all optimizing before any user actually complains, so may be overoptimizing.