# Decompress gzip and zlib string in javascript

Tags: javascript, gzip, zlib, compression, tmx

I want to get compress layer data from tmx file . Who knows libraries for decompress gzip and zlib string in javascript ? I try [zlib](https://github.com/imaya/zlib.js) but it doesn't work for me . Ex , layer data in tmx file is :

```
  <data encoding="base64" compression="zlib">
       eJztwTEBAAAAwqD1T20JT6AAAHgaCWAAAQ==
  </data>
```

My javascript code is

```
var base64Data = "eJztwTEBAAAAwqD1T20JT6AAAHgaCWAAAQ==";
var compressData = atob(base64Data);
var inflate = new Zlib.Inflate(compressData);
var output = inflate.decompress();
```

It runs with displays message error "unsupported compression method" . But I try decompress with online tool as http://i-tools.org/gzip , it returns correct string.

Comment: Thanks for the question (even if encoding compressed data as base64 seems a little perverse in that base64 is a negative-compression format; I can see the applications...)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I can solve my problem by [zlib](https://github.com/imaya/zlib.js) . I fix my code as below

```
var base64Data = "eJztwTEBAAAAwqD1T20JT6AAAHgaCWAAAQ==";
var compressData = atob(base64Data);
var compressData = compressData.split('').map(function(e) {
    return e.charCodeAt(0);
});
var inflate = new Zlib.Inflate(compressData);
var output = inflate.decompress();
```

Comment: I have a zip file in a normal JavaScript string retrieved over a network url - How do I decompress it so I can use its original 'text-plain' content?

Answer (score 55):

[Pako](https://github.com/nodeca/pako) is a full and modern `Zlib` port.

Here is a very simple example and you can work from there.

Get [pako.js](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nodeca/pako/master/dist/pako.js) and you can decompress byteArray like so:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Gunzipping binary gzipped string</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="pako.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">

    // Get datastream as Array, for example:
    var charData    = [31,139,8,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,5,193,219,13,0,16,16,4,192,86,214,151,102,52,33,110,35,66,108,226,60,218,55,147,164,238,24,173,19,143,241,18,85,27,58,203,57,46,29,25,198,34,163,193,247,106,179,134,15,50,167,173,148,48,0,0,0];

    // Turn number array into byte-array
    var binData     = new Uint8Array(charData);

    // Pako magic
    var data        = pako.inflate(binData);

    // Convert gunzipped byteArray back to ascii string:
    var strData     = String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint16Array(data));

    // Output to console
    console.log(strData);

  </script>
</head>
<body>
    Open up the developer console.
</body>
</html>
```

Running example: http://jsfiddle.net/9yH7M/

Alternatively you can base64 encode the array before you send it over as the Array takes up a lot of overhead when sending as JSON or XML. Decode likewise:

```
// Get some base64 encoded binary data from the server. Imagine we got this:
var b64Data     = 'H4sIAAAAAAAAAwXB2w0AEBAEwFbWl2Y0IW4jQmziPNo3k6TuGK0Tj/ESVRs6yzkuHRnGIqPB92qzhg8yp62UMAAAAA==';

// Decode base64 (convert ascii to binary)
var strData     = atob(b64Data);

// Convert binary string to character-number array
var charData    = strData.split('').map(function(x){return x.charCodeAt(0);});

// Turn number array into byte-array
var binData     = new Uint8Array(charData);

// Pako magic
var data        = pako.inflate(binData);

// Convert gunzipped byteArray back to ascii string:
var strData     = String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint16Array(data));

// Output to console
console.log(strData);
```

Running example: http://jsfiddle.net/9yH7M/1/

To go more advanced, here is the [`pako` API documentation](http://nodeca.github.io/pako/).

Comment: The html example probably will not work as it is, because `pako` is not defined. The API has changed maybe, it uses  `require` now.

Comment: Note: `String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint16Array(data))` fails for long input (Maximum call stack size exceeded, JavaScript) This should work for longer arrays: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20604561/774398

Comment: For long strings, use `var string = new TextDecoder("utf-8").decode(data)` as mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8936984/uint8array-to-string-in-javascript

Comment: I meet a problem.When I decompress  use pako the english is okay, but when meet Chinese the Chinese string would become unreadable code.I don't know why.The gzip compression would remove the chart-set infomation??

Answer (score 10):

For anyone using Ruby on Rails, who wants to send compressed encoded data to the browser, then uncompress it via Javascript on the browser, I've combined both excellent answers above into the following solution. Here's the Rails server code in my application controller which compresses and encodes a string before sending it the browser via a *@variable* to a *.html.erb* file:

```
require 'zlib'
require 'base64'

    def compressor (some_string)
        Base64.encode64(Zlib::Deflate.deflate(some_string))
    end
```

Here's the Javascript function, which uses pako.min.js:

```
function uncompress(input_field){
    base64data = document.getElementById(input_field).innerText;
    compressData = atob(base64data);
    compressData = compressData.split('').map(function(e) {
        return e.charCodeAt(0);
    });
    binData = new Uint8Array(compressData);
    data = pako.inflate(binData);
    return String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint16Array(data));
}
```

Here's a javascript call to that uncompress function, which wants to unencode and uncompress data stored inside a hidden HTML field:

```
my_answer = uncompress('my_hidden_field');
```

Here's the entry in the Rails *application.js* file to call *pako.min.js*, which is in the */vendor/assets/javascripts* directory:

```
//= require pako.min
```

And I got the *pako.min.js* file from here:

https://github.com/nodeca/pako/tree/master/dist

All works at my end, anyway! :-)

Answer (score 0):

I was sending data from a Python script and trying to decode it in JS. Here's what I had to do:

Python

```py
import base64
import json
import urllib.parse
import zlib

...

data_object = {
    '_id': '_id',
    ...
}
compressed_details = base64.b64encode(zlib.compress(bytes(json.dumps(data_object), 'utf-8'))).decode("ascii")
urlsafe_object = urllib.parse.quote(str(compressed_details))#.replace('%', '\%') # you likely don't need this last part
final_URL = f'https://my.domain.com?data_object={urlsafe_object}'

...
```

JS

```js
// npm install this
import pako from 'pako';

...

const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
const data_object = urlParams.get('data_object');
if (data_object) {
    const compressedData = Uint8Array.from(window.atob(data_object), (c) => c.charCodeAt(0));
    originalObject = JSON.parse(pako.inflate(compressedData, { to: 'string' }));
};

...
```