# How to unzip a gzipped file

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, gzip

I have a JSON file that is `gzipped`.

I can download the zipped file with `jQuery ajax`.

I need t help with unzipping the zip file so I can read the JSON data.

Comment: This is not what jQuery is for (except the ajax part). Remember jQuery is not a language, it's a DOM manipulation library.

Comment: @evolutionxbox so, explain how can I download a file in client side??

Comment: [Always read the documentation!](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/)

Comment: ok. it is written in documentation that I can download a file using jquery ajax.

Comment: Using ajax, you can get the file. Then you must use a library to decompress it, such as [zlib](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14620769/decompress-gzip-and-zlib-string-in-javascript). --- (Technically you're asking for a library which is off-topic for SO.)

Comment: @evolutionxbox how are libraries like [tag:jquery] or [tag:zlib] off-topic?

Answer (score 1):

Is the source server under your control also? Because you should not gzip the json and transfer it. The webserver should enable gzip, so all the correct headers are set on the response. If the correct headers are set, the webserver will gzip the file, send it to the browser, the browser will see in the headers that the response is gzipped, it will unzip it and you have plain text json in your ajax response without taking care of anything.