# Paho javascript mqtt compressed payload

Tags: jquery, compression, mqtt, paho

I am developing a website which can connect to an mqtt broker and get payload messages.

The library I use is (https://eclipse.org/paho/clients/js/).

My problem is the following. When I try to get a standard compressed message (gzipped) the library throw an exception "**Error: AMQJS0009E Malformed UTF data:f5 3 -52**."

How can I handle compressed messages?

here is my code:

```
var selected_tags   = '';
var checked_tags    = [];

var hostname        = 'xxx';
var port            = 80;
var qos             = 1;

var user            = 'xxx';
var pass            = 'xxx';

var keepAlive       = 60;
var timeout         = 3;
var ssl             = false;
var cleanSession    = true;
var lastWillTopic   = '';
var lastWillQos     = 1;
var lastWillRetain  = false;
var lastWillMessage = '';
var g_topic;
var client = new Messaging.Client(hostname, port, "myclientid_" + parseInt(Math.random() * 100, 10));

var options = {
    timeout             : 3,
    userName            : user,
    password            : pass,
    keepAliveInterval   : keepAlive,
    cleanSession        : cleanSession,
    useSSL              : ssl,
    onSuccess           : function () {
        console_log('<span style="color:green">Connected</span>');
    },
    onFailure           : function (message) {
        console_log('<span style="color:red">Connection failed: ' + message.errorMessage + '</span>');
        client.connect(options);
    }
};
function _subscribe(){
    g_topic = $("#sel_reader").val();
    console_log('<span style="color:green">subscribe to: ' + g_topic + '</span>');
    client.subscribe(g_topic, {qos: qos});
    $("#_subscribe").addClass('hide');
    $("#_unsubscribe").removeClass('hide');
}
function _unsubscribe(){
    console_log('<span style="color:red">unsubscribe from: ' + g_topic + '</span>');
    client.unsubscribe(g_topic);
    $("#_subscribe").removeClass('hide');
    $("#_unsubscribe").addClass('hide');
}
client.onConnectionLost = function (responseObject) {
    console_log('<span style="color:red">Connection lost: ' + responseObject.errorMessage + '</span>');
    client.connect(options);
};
client.onMessageArrived = function (message) {
    // console.log("message arrived");

    var live_search = [];
    var live_found  = '';
    var json = JSON.parse(message.payloadString);

    console_log('<hr />Message Recieved: Topic: ' + message.destinationName + '<br />' 
                  +message.payloadString + 
                '. QoS: ' + message.qos
    );

};
var publish = function (payload, topic, qos) {
    var message = new Messaging.Message(payload);
    message.destinationName = topic;
    message.qos = qos;
    client.send(message);
}
function console_log(txt){
    $("#console").append('<b>'+txt + "</b><br />");
}
var prev_imei = '';
var find = ':';
var re   = new RegExp(find, 'g');
function SortByRssi(a, b){
    var arssi = a.rssi;
    var brssi = b.rssi; 
    return ((arssi > brssi) ? -1 : ((arssi < brssi) ? 1 : 0));
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    client.connect(options);
});
```

Comment: Edit the question to show the code you are using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so there is no built in handling of gzip compressed payloads in MQTT or the Paho Javascript client.

This means when your code runs it tries to parse a gzip stream as a UTF-8 string.

```
client.onMessageArrived = function (message) {
    // console.log("message arrived");

    var live_search = [];
    var live_found  = '';
    var json = JSON.parse(message.payloadString);

    console_log('<hr />Message Recieved: Topic: ' + message.destinationName + '<br />' 
                  +message.payloadString + 
                '. QoS: ' + message.qos
    );
};
```

To start with you need to work with the raw bytes not the string form of the message. You can access the raw bytes fromt the `message.payloadBytes` field.

Now you have the problem of actually decompressing it. This older [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14620769/decompress-gzip-and-zlib-string-in-javascript) looks like it would help.

```
client.onMessageArrived = function (message) {
    // console.log("message arrived");

    var live_search = [];
    var live_found  = '';
    var compressedJSON = message.payloadBytes;
    var json = pako.inflate(compressedJSON);
    console.log('<hr />Message Recieved: Topic: ' + message.destinationName + '<br />' 
              + json + 
            '. QoS: ' + message.qos
    );
};
```

Answer (score 3):

In case someone needs the answer for Python:

```
import zlib

def _on_message(self, mqttc, obj, msg):
    dec_msg = zlib.decompress(msg.payload)
    # do whatever you need with dec_msg
    print dec_msg
```

Comment: Consider providing asnwers in language from question tags - your code _may_ or _may not_ be useful to the question author.

Comment: The question is about working with the Paho Javascript client running in the browser, so this does not answer the question

Comment: I agree with you, but on the other hand when I was looking to get the answer for python, I could not find anything. Google bring me to this topic, so maybe one day someone also find it here.