# how to decode gzip string in JS

Tags: javascript, django, python-3.x, gzip

I have one Django app and in the view of that I am using gzip_str(str) method to compress data and send back to the browser. Now I want to get the original string back in the browser. How can I decode the string in JS.

P.S. I have found few questions here related to the javascript decode of gzip string but I could not figure out how to use those. Please tell me how can I decode and get the original string.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Decompress gzip and zlib string in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14620769/decompress-gzip-and-zlib-string-in-javascript)

Answer (score -1):

There is javascript library called [gzip-js](https://github.com/beatgammit/gzip-js) you could try this.

```
var out = gzip.unzip(data, options);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. Could you please tell me what will be the "options" in case when the data is compressed using gzip_str(str) function.

Comment: if you look at the pull request of this github repository there is a fixed version of the [gzip-js](https://github.com/coolaj86/gzip-js) you can use this version  without passing options.

Comment: I tried to copy that file and added in my html when I am running the application it is giving error "Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined". how to solve this. Exactly which JS file need to included in the html to use the gzip.unzip function.

Comment: According to its documentation, `gzip-js` can only compress, not decompress.

Answer (score -1):

Serve the string with an appropriate `Content-Encoding`, then the browser will decode it for you.