# Decompress zlib string vanilla js

Tags: javascript, zlib

I have an string of UTF-8 characters which is compressed with ZLib. Now i want to decompress it, but the only way i can find is with an Uint8Array, for which i didnt found a way to convert the string to.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Decompress gzip and zlib string in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14620769/decompress-gzip-and-zlib-string-in-javascript)

Comment: Ive tried it, since i do have an array with ints representing the utf8 characters but i only get this error: "Uncaught incorrect data check"

Comment: I maybe should add that i have an base45 encoded string, which i then decode and then try to de-zlib. Ive tried the base45 decoder, it works, but im not sure if the array it first produces and makes a string from it is the coreect inoit format. so i tried to use the string.

Comment: You might be better off posting some of your actual data so people can get a clearer idea of what you're talking about.

Comment: You didn't find a way to convert _what_ to _what_ exactly?

Comment: I do have the compressed string "eJzzSM3JyVcIzy/KSVEEABxJBD4=", or the array "101,74,122,122,83,77,51,74,121,86,99,73,122,121,47,75,83,86,69,69,65,66,120,74,66,68,52,61" ) which are the decimal representaions of the characters. No i want to decompress it ("Hello World!").