# Python's zlib decompresses data, but Pako (JavaScript zlib) fails

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, zlib

I'm trying to inflate some zlib compressed data (Ren'Py Archive 3 archive file structure for those wondering) with JavaScript, but I can't seem to reproduce the Python behavior in Node.js.

This Python script works:

```py
import zlib

# Data written to a file from a different Python script, for demo purposes
# This would be a value in memory in JS
data = open("py", "rb")

# Works
print(
    zlib.decompress(data.read(), 0)
)
```

While this Node.js script:

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const pako = require('pako');

const data = fs.readFileSync('py', 'binary');

// Doesn't work
console.log(
    pako.inflateRaw(data)
);
```

Throws this error:

```
C:\Users\gunne\Documents\Programming\node.js\rpa-extractor\node_modules\pako\lib\inflate.js:384
  if (inflator.err) throw inflator.msg || msg[inflator.err];
                    ^
invalid stored block lengths
(Use `node --trace-uncaught ...` to show where the exception was thrown)
```

As per the Python zlib.decompress documentation, a wbits parameter (the second parameter) of `0` "automatically [determines] the window size from the zlib header," something that the Pako implementation seemingly doesn't do.

Am I doing something incorrectly? How would I achieve the same output as in Python using Node.js?

**Edit**:

Here's the data (replace the readFileSync line with this):

```
const data = Buffer.from(
    // Output of Buffer.from(data).toString('hex');
    '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'
    , 'hex'
).toString('binary');
```

**Edit #2**:

As per help of Mark Adler, the solution for me was to downgrade to pako version `1.0.11`, as that seems to handle it via `pako.inflate`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `inflate` instead of `inflateRaw`.

Comment: I tried this, but I get an `unknown compression method` error.

Comment: Post in your question a hex dump of `data` from `const data = fs.readFileSync('py', 'binary');`.

Comment: Alright, it should be on the question now.

Comment: That's a perfectly fine zlib stream. I tried feeding that data to `pako.inflate()` in a node.js playground (codesandbox.io), and it worked fine. No errors. Decompressed the data correctly.

Comment: Weird. It seems to work on pako version `1.0.11`, but not the latest one. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

pako since v2.x has dropped support for binary Strings and Arrays. You can now only provide compressed data as Uin8Array instead. ([source](https://github.com/nodeca/pako/issues/205#issuecomment-742860272))

Examples of this can be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72947382/8285811) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14620769/8285811).