# Compress with Python Zlib, decompress in JavaScript Zlib

Tags: javascript, python, compression, zlib

Trying to compress some data in Python (think API backend) then open and decompress in JS (frontend).

Python

```py
zlib.compress(bytes(json.dumps(["a", "b", "c"]), "utf-8"))
```

This produces a byte object

```
b'x\x9c\x8bVJT\xd2QPJ\x02\x11\xc9J\xb1\x00\x1a\x13\x03C'
```

How do I parse this and decompress this with JavaScript?

Comment: I don't think JS can interpret Python's representation of `bytes`. base64 encode the `bytes` that `zlib.compress` returns - `base64.b64encode(zlib.compress(bytes(json.dumps(["a", "b", "c"]), "utf-8"))).decode('ascii')`.

Comment: @python_user I'm trying to use pako but I don't know how to convert the Python byte object to Uint8Array which pako is expecting.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @GordonAitchJay for the tip there. Got there in the end.

On the Python side we have

```
json_object = ["a", "b", "c"]
base64.b64encode(zlib.compress(bytes(json.dumps(json_object), "utf-8"))).decode("ascii")
```

On the JS side we have

```
let compressedData = Uint8Array.from(atob(input), (c) => c.charCodeAt(0));
let decompressedData = pako.inflate(compressedData, { to: "string" });
let jsonObject = JSON.parse(decompressedData);
```

Comment: Very helpful! Was missing the base64 encoding and the whole conversion stuff on JS side. Works like a charm now! You would imagine this would be easier..