# have tabulator using a gz compressed json file without enabling compression on the web server

Tags: javascript, ajax, compression, tabulator

I can't change the web server so I can't enable compression on the .json file automatically. This would be my ideal solution.

I would like tabulator to pull down a json file that is compressed to a gz file, but I don't know if it's possible or what I would need to do in order to tell it to decompress it before trying to use it.

Is there a way to set the ajaxURL to gz and it work?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `ajaxResponse` callback to take the incoming compressed data and then decompress it before passing it into Tabulator.

In this example im going to use the advice of this [GZip Stack Overflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14620769/decompress-gzip-and-zlib-string-in-javascript) so you will need to copy the `uncompress` function from there

```js
var table = new Tabulator("#exmaple-table", {
    ...other table config
    ajaxResponse:function(url, params, response){
        return uncompress(response);
    },
});
```

Full details of the `ajaxResponse` callback can be found in the [Ajax Documentation](http://tabulator.info/docs/5.1/data#ajax)