# Javascript gzip decompression

Tags: javascript, c#, gzip, compression

I want do decompress images in JavaScript. I have compressed the images with C# using *gzip*. How do I decompress *gzipped* data in JavaScript?

C# code

```
public static byte[] Compress(byte[] raw)
{
    using (MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (GZipStream gzip = new GZipStream(memory, CompressionMode.Compress, true))
        {
            gzip.Write(raw, 0, raw.Length);
        }
        return memory.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no JS accessible builtin in browsers. You need to use a search engine of your choice to find a library. Is your question browser or node.js related? Btw.: Usually compression is the job of the webserver, so you won't need to compress explicitly.

Comment: See this duplicate and the original http://stackoverflow.com/q/14630238/495455

Comment: What type of images are we talking about? Did you check wether they actually get compressed or wether they turn out bigger after the "compression"? Why do you think you need to compress these images "manually"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Decompress gzip and zlib string in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14620769/decompress-gzip-and-zlib-string-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

First of all you have to close the `GZipStream` when you are done with it.

```
public static byte[] Compress(byte[] raw)
{
    using (MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (GZipStream gzip = new GZipStream(memory, CompressionMode.Compress, true))
        {
            gzip.Write(raw, 0, raw.Length);
            gzip.Close();
        }
        return memory.ToArray();
    }
}
```

You can use [pako](https://github.com/nodeca/pako) for decompressing in javascript.

```
var base64Data = "COMPRESSED_BASE64_GZIP";
var compressData = atob(base64Data);
compressData = compressData.split('').map(function (e) {
    return e.charCodeAt(0);
});

var originalText = pako.ungzip(compressData, {to:"string"});
```