# Debuging a decompression error with Zlib.js

Tags: javascript, php, compression, zlib, deflate

I am trying to compress text server side in PHP using the `gzdeflate` function and send that data to the clients browser which will then inflate it.

I did some research and found the imaya Zlib.js source on GitHub and attempted to use that. Unfortunately, I always get an "unsupported compression method" error when I try to inflate my data.

I've read the documents with no luck and I have search the web for more information.

I found these two links, but wasn't able get any positive results.
[ZLIB Decompression - Client Side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4507316/zlib-decompression-client-side)
[Decompress gzip and zlib string in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14620769/decompress-gzip-and-zlib-string-in-javascript)

**Questions:**
1) Are there any tutorials on how to use these libraries available?
2) If not would anyone have any information as to why I would be getting the error message that I am?

Thanks for any help or information that you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gzdeflate.php

- gzencode() == gzip
- gzcompress() == zlib (aka. HTTP deflate)
- gzdeflate()  == *raw* deflate encoding

I think that you must call gzcompress() for zlib compression.