# Using pako to decode a compressed stream of data

Tags: javascript

I try to use an example shown here: [zlib-decompression-client-side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4507316/zlib-decompression-client-side)

but I am unable to use the sample shown on JSfidle: [decompress byteArray](http://jsfiddle.net/9yH7M/)

I downloaded pako.js but no success. I even tried to copy the code given about the sample: [pako.js](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nodeca/pako/master/dist/pako.js)

but I keep getting an error.

```
var charData = [31, 139, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 5, 193, 219, 13, 0, 16, 16, 4, 192, 86, 214, 151, 102, 52, 33, 110, 35, 66, 108, 226, 60, 218, 55, 147, 164, 238, 24, 173, 19, 143, 241, 18, 85, 27, 58, 203, 57, 46, 29, 25, 198, 34, 163, 193, 247, 106, 179, 134, 15, 50, 167, 173, 148, 48, 0, 0, 0];

var binData = new Uint8Array(charData);
** here I get error: Typed array constructor argument is invalid **

// Pako magic
var data = pako.inflate(binData);

// Convert gunzipped byteArray back to ascii string:
var strData = String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint16Array(data));

// Output to console
alert(strData);
```

any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see it helps

```
var binData = new Uint32Array(charData);
```

Comment: It give the same error. remember that the exact same code is working on JSFidle

Comment: Please explain. I thought that is exactly what I did: left a comment below his answer