# Gzip string in javascript using pako.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, compression, gzip

I read a topic about decompress a string in javascript using pako.js
[ZLIB Decompression - Client Side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4507316/zlib-decompression-client-side)
http://jsfiddle.net/9yH7M/1/
This is code to decompress

```
// Get some base64 encoded binary data from the server. Imagine we got this:
var b64Data     = 'H4sIAAAAAAAAAwXB2w0AEBAEwFbWl2Y0IW4jQmziPNo3k6TuGK0Tj/ESVRs6yzkuHRnGIqPB92qzhg8yp62UMAAAAA==';

// Decode base64 (convert ascii to binary)
var strData     = atob(b64Data);

// Convert binary string to character-number array
var charData    = strData.split('').map(function(x){return x.charCodeAt(0);});

// Turn number array into byte-array
var binData     = new Uint8Array(charData);

// Pako magic
var data        = pako.inflate(binData);

// Convert gunzipped byteArray back to ascii string:
var strData     = String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint16Array(data));

// Output to console
console.log(strData);
```

I want a method to compress string and ouput can be decompress by above code
How can do that

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14620769/decompress-gzip-and-zlib-string-in-javascript ?  Inflate means decompress, Deflate means compress, ... https://nodeca.github.io/pako/#Deflate has example too ?

Comment: Your topic is mention topic in my question. It's not have compress string

Comment: The only matter missing in the example is to conversion of the binary output data (from `Deflate.result`) into BASE64 but there is `btoa()` right ?  https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/Base64_encoding_and_decoding

Comment: var str = "Nguyen ANh Duc";           

            var data = pako.deflate(str);

            alert(btoa(data));

Comment: this is my code but can not get right result. sorry i'm newbie

Comment: Oh, i fix this issue, i found error in pako.js, fix it and every thing is OK, thanks you man

Answer (score 2):

After wasting 2 hours trying more than 20 answers on different site, I figured out the how to gzip & base64. It's so simple:

```js
var your_input_string = "hello hello hello!";
var compressed_uint8array = pako.gzip(your_input_string);
var b64encoded_string = btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, compressed_uint8array));
console.log(b64encoded_string);
```

You need to include `pako.js`. Refer to this answer to learn how to get it: [How to use pako.js javascript? Pako is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38882741/how-to-use-pako-js-javascript-pako-is-not-defined)

Comment: When using your code (with typescript), I get the following error : `Argument of type 'Uint8Array' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number[]'`. `fromCharCode()` is expecting `number[]` type as input parameter. Any ideas how to solve this ?

Comment: For anyone looking for a solution to the typescript error above, I changed the third line to `btoa(String.fromCharCode(...compressed_uint8array))`. Source : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75961365/argument-of-type-uint8array-is-not-assignable-to-parameter-of-type-number

Answer (score 1):

- The code to decompress from `b64Data` can be simplified:

```
return pako.inflate(atob(b64Data), { to: 'string' });
```

- The code to compress to `b64Data`:

```
return btoa(pako.deflate(stringToCompress, { to: 'string' }));
```

Comment: does not work with gzip part, gzip gives uint8array

Answer (score 0):

You can do following:

```
var binData = pako.deflate( "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".split("")
.map(function(x){return x.charCodeAt(0);}));
```

yields:

> binData : Uint8Array(37) [120, 156, 115, 116, 114, 118, 113, 117, 115, 247, 240, 244, 242, 246, 241, 245, 243, 15, 8, 12, 10, 14, 9, 13, 11, 143, 136, 140, 114, 196, 41, 3, 0, 150, 1, 15, 191]

```
var strData = String.fromCharCode.apply(null, pako.inflate(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, binData).split("").  map(function(x){return x.charCodeAt(0);})));

//yields back
```

> "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *why* and/or *how* this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

i did this in php:

```php
echo 'id: ' . $id . "\n";
echo 'event: ping' . "\n";
 echo 'data:' . base64_encode(gzdeflate(json_encode(['time' => microtime(true), 'date' => date('Y-m-d- H:i:s')]), 9)) . "\n";
echo "\n\n";
```

as a server sent event with a compressed json data

and this in javascript to:

```js
const eventSource = new EventSource(sse.url,{
        withCredentials: true,
});
eventSource.addEventListener('ping', (event) => {
        let data = pako.inflate(atob(event.data),{ raw: true, to: 'string' });
        console.log(data);
        console.log('waiting for response');
    });
```