# How to use pako.js javascript? Pako is not defined

Tags: javascript, html, zlib, compression

I'm fairly new to JavaScript. I'm currently working on an algorithm that deflates in Java and inflates in javascript. For the most part, I have heard that pako.js is a good tool to use for decompression but I'm having problems implementing it. I created a function in JavaScript that passes the base64 string as a parameter.

```
function decompressHtml(html){

                var compressedData = atob(html);
                var charData = compressedData.split('').map(function(x){return x.charCodeAt(0);});
                var binData = new Uint8Array(charData);
                var inflated = '';


                try {
                  inflated = pako.inflate(binData);

                } catch (err) {
                  console.log(err);
                }

                return inflated;

        }
```

It always returns an error that says that pako is not properly defined. Is there a specific script tag/s that need to be inserted in order to define pako? I realise this may be a simple question to answer but I'm not sure of the answer.

Comment: Have you...included pako on the page?

Comment: I have actually..that's the confusing part

Comment: You can include the pako from CDN https://www.jsdelivr.com/package/npm/pako

Answer (score 12):

1. Download pako.js or pako.min.js from [official pako github page](https://github.com/nodeca/pako/tree/master/dist)
2. Include the downloaded file in your html as follows:

   `<script type="text/javascript" src="pako.js"></script>`

**Sample code:**

```
var input = "test string";
var output = pako.gzip(input,{ to: 'string' });
alert("compressed gzip string - " + output);
var originalInput = pako.ungzip(output,{ to: 'string' });
alert("uncompressed string - " + originalInput);
```

Comment: Your example is good, but your second alert is wrong because in both cases you're giving `output`, but the second one should be `originalInput`.

Comment: @RobKwasowski Thanks for the review. Corrected it. Cheers

Answer (score 3):

**This will help you**

**Decompress**

```
const input = new Uint8Array(res);
const restored = JSON.parse(pako.inflate(input, { to: 'string'}));
console.log(restored)
```

**Compress**

```
const input = new Uint8Array(res);
const output = pako.deflate(input);
console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

Pako expects to be bound to an object named `global`, which is (as of Chrome 118) undefined in the browser. You can create the `global` object and make Pako happy by putting this in a script somewhere before Pako's script tag.

```
if (!window.global) window.global = window;
```