# How to decompress an object compressed by zlib in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, compression, zlib, zopfli

In JavaScript project, I want to decompress an object compressed by zlib([Zopfli.js](https://github.com/imaya/zopfli.js)) and I'm trying it with [pako.min.js](https://github.com/nodeca/pako/tree/master/dist).
However, the example at [the official site of pako](https://github.com/nodeca/pako) uses `require` function which does not exist in JavaScript. Maybe `Node.js` has this but I'm afraid it would take a lot of time and pains to combine this JavaScript project with `Node.js`, because I know nothing about `Node.js`.

Is it any way to get through with this, or another way to decompress the object?

Any information would be appreciated.

### What I've already tried

I've already tried [zlib.js](https://github.com/imaya/zlib.js) library for decomressing, but the result is catching the error below which I couldn't find any solution:

```
const compressed = dataCompressedByZlib;
const inflate = new Zlib.Inflate(compressed);
const plain = inflate.decompress();// -> input buffer is broken
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use pako.js from [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nodeca/pako/master/dist/pako.js) for client side javascript and import it as -

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="pako.js"></script>
```

inside your html, as mentioned here-

https://stackoverflow.com/a/22675078/7895283