# Strange behavior in gzip pako inflate function

Tags: javascript, format, unzip, pako

SO I'm trying to work around a dezip problem that I have.

I feel that I am close to getting what I want but do not understand why or where I mess up.

```js
  compressedData = "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"

  // string to base64
  strData = atob(compressedData);
  // string to number array
  charData = strData.split('').map(function(x){return x.charCodeAt(0);});
  // number array to byte array
  binData = new Uint16Array(charData);
  // Pako magic
  data = pako.inflate(binData, {to: "string"});
  // byte array unzip to string
  strData = new TextDecoder("utf-8").decode(data);

  console.log(strData);
```

In my code above you can probably recognize some unzip, It comes from this old post:
[ZLIB Decompression - Client Side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4507316/zlib-decompression-client-side)

using pako.js library :
https://www.npmjs.com/package/pako

I can't get what I missed to get a bad result having all kind of symboles, it is however kinda good? see below:

```
 � §8[§8⚔§8]

display   Lore  # §7Health: §a+421 §e(+60)
```

I don't know if the problem is coming from me or the library (not gonna lie, it's probably me... ) neather how to fix it.

Any help is appreciated,

ty :)

Comment: What should the output be?

Comment: json like, so with some {"a": "b"} stuff

Comment: I think your compressedData is bad.  It seems to have html entities in it like `&quot;` and `&amp;`.  I took your code and the compressedData from the other post and it works - https://jsfiddle.net/Lsdy1vn8/

Comment: so from what you say, if I do not print it as text but display it as html should work?

Comment: The data contained in compressedData is invalid.  When you run it through atob and log it, you see html entities.  I don’t know where you got this data from.

Comment: TY for that, now I know where to look! The API I'm using don't have much documentation about this part of the process. So I try to figure out stuff by myself. It is the Minecraft Hypixel API (Skyblock related). It is a MMORPG like game, and what you have in your hands is my stuff :)

Comment: How did you ended up seeing thoses html elements? That interests me a lot

Comment: I was wrong about the html entities, that was a side-effect of using [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/57fLrx6e/1)'s console instead of devtools.  I stand by compressedData being bad in some way just not the way I thought.

Comment: too bad, well back to some research... ty for your idea. About the API being wrong, I'm pretty sure it cannot be since it is used by there own systems

Comment: I don't know what API you mean, is that where you are getting compressedData?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256662/discussion-between-ren-and-james).